# Relationship of attachments to attachmentdescriptions

Tags: vulkan

A render pass has a framebuffer whose image views serve as attachments. A render pass also has an array of `VkAttachmentDescriptions` that provide information about its attachments.

But the specification doesn't explicitly say how the attachments are related to the descriptions. That is, it doesn't say that the first `VkAttachmentDescription` corresponds to the first attachment, the second description corresponds to the second attachment, and so on.

The text from the specification is:

> pAttachments points to an array of attachmentCount number of
>   VkAttachmentDescription  structures describing properties of the
>   attachments, or NULL if attachmentCount is zero.

Can we assume that there is always a one-to-one correspondence between a render pass's attachments and its attachment descriptions?

Thanks.

Comment: "*A render pass has a framebuffer whose image views serve as attachments.*" No, a render pass *instance* has a framebuffer. A render pass just has a template for what the framebuffer will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the specification doesn't explicitly say how the attachments are related to the descriptions.

Sure it does:

> `pAttachments` is an array of `VkImageView` handles, each of which will be used as the corresponding attachment in a render pass instance.

That's [from the specification on `VkFramebufferCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#_framebuffers). The validity rules also make this clear:

> `attachmentCount` must be equal to the attachment count specified in `renderPass`.

Further elements from `VkFramebufferCreatInfo`'s validity rules:

> Any given element of `pAttachments` must have been created with an `VkFormat` value that matches the `VkFormat` specified by the corresponding `VkAttachmentDescription` in `renderPass`.

There are several validity rules of the form "Any given element of `pAttachments` [must match some property of] the corresponding `VkAttachmentDescription` in `renderPass`." So that is how they are related.

Comment: It's clear that the framebuffer's image views serve as the attachments, but my question involves the attachment descriptions (VkAttachmentDescriptions). Your quotes of the spec don't say anything about the attachment descriptions.

Comment: Yes, that certainly implies that each attachment has a corresponding VkAttachmentDescription. Many thanks.